# Redirect rule in htaccess get error message

Tags: .htaccess

I wrote this rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule /(\d+)*$ ./index.php?id=$1
```

But in case "http://myfunnydomain.hu/123"  I get the mesage: 
'The requested URL /123 was not found on this server.'

So what is wrong?  :)

Thank you, M

Answer (score 1):

The URI does not start with a `/`. To mark the start of the URI, use a `^`. This is the character used in regular expressions to mark the start of a string. You can read a detailed explanation about start and end of string/line anchors [over here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)*$ ./index.php?id=$1
```